# Jboss Startup error

Tags: jboss, jboss-mdb

On an existing application I am trying to startup the JBOSS server and I get following error.

Unfortunately I do not know clearly as yet, what all has been configured and is being used on this jboss. For now; I quickly want to get the error sorted out.

If looking at the stack trace, you can suggest what kind of configuration is missing or what I should be looking at to fix this problem; then I'll be really grateful.

any help is appreciated.

------------------After Skaffman's help below; I was able to reduce the stacktrace to this------------------

```
07:36:36,971 ERROR [URLDeploymentScanner] Incomplete Deployment listing:

--- MBeans waiting for other MBeans ---
ObjectName: xyz.management:service=Queue,name=managementQueue
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer

ObjectName: xyz.management:service=Queue,name=indexQueue
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer

ObjectName: xyz.management:service=Queue,name=adaptiveLearningQueue
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer

ObjectName: xyz.management:service=Queue,name=xyzErrorQueue
  State: CONFIGURED
  I Depend On:
    jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer

--- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM ---
ObjectName: jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer
  State: NOTYETINSTALLED
  Depends On Me:
    xyz.management:service=Queue,name=managementQueue
    xyz.management:service=Queue,name=indexQueue
    xyz.management:service=Queue,name=adaptiveLearningQueue
    xyz.management:service=Queue,name=xyzErrorQueue


javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: XAConnectionFactory not bound
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:529)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getBinding(NamingServer.java:537)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.getObject(NamingServer.java:543)
    at org.jnp.server.NamingServer.lookup(NamingServer.java:296)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:627)
    at org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:589)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.jms.DLQHandler.createService(DLQHandler.java:182)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.jbossInternalCreate(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:260)
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceMBeanSupport.create(ServiceMBeanSupport.java:188)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.jms.JMSContainerInvoker.innerStartDelivery(JMSContainerInvoker.java:665)
    at org.jboss.ejb.plugins.jms.JMSContainerInvoker$ExceptionListenerImpl$ExceptionListenerRunnable.run(JMSContainerInvoker.java:1594)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have multiple issues here.

- JBoss is trying to deploy the file `velocity.log` which it has found in its `deploy` directory. This is clearly not what you intended, but realise that any files that get dropped into the `deploy` directory , JBoss will try and deploy. You need to find out what's doing that, and stop it.
- The second problem is that you have a bunch of JMS deployments (e.g. MDBs) somewhere in your application, but JMS is not present (or has not been configured correctly) on this server.

Comment: I wanted to voteup your answer but due to a stackoverflow error couldn't. +1 for the help. It really cleared some things for me

I removed velocity.log and that took away first two errors; which means that it was pointlessly trying to deploy the velocity.log.

Second issue was I had not yet deployed jms-ra.rar, so that took away another hurdle. Now I am finally left with jboss.messaging:service=ServerPeer not being installed.

Could you point out how I could figure out if it's installed? And if not; how could I go about installing it?

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: If something is looking for `ServerPeer`, and it isn't there, then someone's been mucking about with the JBoss configuration, and you have an incomplete configuration. I can't really help you with that, since I don't know what the config is.